# Dynamically displaying third party content in page, across domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I'm using jQuery .ajax to replace the contents of a div within the page using the code below. This works fine as long as the URL points to one of the action methods in my ASP.NET app. But I have a situation where I need to display content from a third party URL (a payments service). This technique won't work because of of the same domain policy. Is there another way I can display this content within the existing page, without loading another page? I'm thinking perhaps there's something I can do with an iframe, but I can't just stick an iframe on the page and set the src attribute, there's data that needs to be posted with the request, as in the example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#getPaymentForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/Home/PostPayment',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': $('#getPaymentForm').serialize(),
            'success': function (result) {
                $('#reload').replaceWith(result);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: If it's cross domain, and there's no CORS headers in the response you cannot use JS. Your options are limited to server side proxy (ie. AJAX to your local server, then make the request to the third party there in C# and return the response to your JS) or iframe - assuming the third party allows `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: Thanks Rory. Can you (or anyone else) expand on the alternatives at all? How would I go about resolving this issue using either a server side proxy or an iframe?

Comment: I found an example of using a proxy (URL below) but apparently it doesn't work with POST and I do need to use POST.
http://www.johnchapman.net/technology/sharepoint/aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/